# Bootstrap 2.3.2 классы управления видимостью в зависимости от размеров

Tags: css, bootstrap

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в `Bootstrap 2.3.2` (из коробки) нет классов для скрытия или отображения элементов верстки в зависимости от размеров устройства и их необходимо самому реализовывать `media` запросами?

Или может быть существуют готовые доп решения для этой версии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует - [Responsive utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html)

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css

Классы для скрытия - `.hidden-phone` `.hidden-tablet` `.hidden-desktop`

Классы для видимости `.visible-phone` `.visible-tablet` `.visible-desktop`

**Пример**

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="visible-desktop">desktop</div>
<div class="visible-tablet">tablet</div>
<div class="visible-phone">phone</div>
```

Comment: Только почему то пример не работает... я вижу текст hidden-desktop
hidden-tablet  на ПК

Comment: Работает пример

Comment: Тогда почему я вижу блоки текста которые не должны отображаться?

Comment: таблицу посмотрите здесь, как работают данные классы - http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html

Comment: да только hidden-desktop я не должен видеть по той таблице, а он у меня отображается.

Comment: а как вы проверяете? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/xr1dkzv3/